# XORing a string of bytes from user input and reversing output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take this code and get it to print back what I gave it.

```
def xorwithmykey(str,key):
    kp = 0
    newbuf = []

    for i in range(len(str)):
        newchar = ord(str[i]) ^ ord(key[kp])
        newbuf.append(chr(newchar))

        kp = kp + 1
        if kp >= len(key):
            kp = 0

    return ''.join(newbuf).encode('hex')
```

I can XOR a key by calling

```
encoded = xorwithmykey('encodethis', 'akey')
```

This gives me back

```
b'04050616050e11110818'
```

Now I want to give that back to the same function to decode.

```
decoded = xorwithmykey(codecs.decode(encoded, 'hex'), codecs.decode('akey', 'hex')
```

This returns a error:

```
binascii.Error: decoding with 'hex' codec failed (Error: Non-hexadecimal digit found)
```

I found this example here:https://snippets.bentasker.co.uk/page-1708032328-XOR-string-against-a-given-key-Python.html

But it is in Python 2 and I am trying to convert to Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you restrict your XOR function to work with bytes alone in Python 3, you can encode/decode any Unicode string:

```
from binascii import hexlify

# Shorter version
# def xorwithmykey(s,key):
#     return bytes([c ^ key[i%len(key)] for i,c in enumerate(s)])

def xorwithmykey(s,key):
    kp = 0
    newbuf = []

    for i in range(len(s)):
        newchar = s[i] ^ key[kp]
        newbuf.append(newchar)

        kp = kp + 1
        if kp >= len(key):
            kp = 0

    return bytes(newbuf)

encoded = xorwithmykey('She said, "你好！"'.encode(), b'akey')
print(hexlify(encoded))

decoded = xorwithmykey(encoded, b'akey')
print(decoded.decode())
```

Output:

```
b'32030059120a0c1d4d4b479ddccb80dcdc84d9f843'
She said, "你好！"
```